# Make tootipster popup not hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltipster

I have using tooltipster and don't want to hide it on mouseover, etc.

Here is code I have using

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").tooltipster({
contentAsHTML: true,
placement: "auto",
content: $("#a1").html()
```

});

I tried to use `timer:500,` and `autoClose: true`, but it not works. When I mouseover tooltipster, it hides.

How I can prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `autoClose: false` option to disable automatic closure of the tooltip.

Refer to [`Tooltipster Options`](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options) > `Trigger` & `TriggerClose` if you need to manually close the tooltip.

---

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").tooltipster({
  contentAsHTML: true,
  placement: "auto",
  autoClose: false,
  content: $("#a1").html()
});
```

```css
div:not(#a1) {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div data-toggle="popover"></div>

<div id="a1">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: hm. tooltipster works great, I just don't need it to hide

Comment: You want it to stay on the page when the mouse leaves the div? @EugeneSukh

Comment: Yes. I want this

Comment: @EugeneSukh done. You have to pass `autoClose : False` option

Comment: Refer to [`Tooltipster Docs`](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#getting-started) and look into `trigger` and `triggerClose` options. This will allow you to close the tooltip once you don't need it open anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174815/discussion-between-alex-and-eugene-sukh).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").tooltipster({
  contentAsHTML: true,
  placement: "auto",
  trigger: 'custom',
  triggerClose: {
    click: false,
    mouseenter: false
  }
  content: $("#a1").html()
});
```

Set trigglerClose events to false

Edit: To use trigglerClose you need to set trigger as 'custom'. Thanks Maxim Mazurok.

Comment: `triggerClose` only applies if 'trigger' is set to 'custom'

Comment: I think, trigger: sustom crashed it